# How I get 3. th party dependencies from my NuGet Server in NAnt?

Tags: .net, jenkins, nuget, nant

I have some questions about .NET process automation. My idea is to use NAnt as Build Automation Tool for the Jenkins CI Server. The Jenkins is running in a Tomcat on a Debian Linux.

In my project I have some dependencies e.g. the Entity Framework. The dependencies are managed in our own NuGet Server. I need also the benefit of versioning, because not all sub projects works with the newest library version.

**Question :** How I get 3rd party dependencies from my NuGet Server in NAnt to run a compile?

I know there is a custom NAnt task for NuGet but I can find any [documentation how to use this task](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/403701).

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if there is no document, you can check the source code of NAnt extension. As long as you are familiar with C#, you will find the code are self-describing.

If you are asking about [nuget-update](https://github.com/Alxandr/NAnt.Nuget.Tasks/blob/master/src/NAnt.Nuget.Tasks/Tasks/NugetGetFilesTask.cs), from the source you can see:

```
[TaskName("nuget-update")]
public class NugetUpdateTask : Task
{
    [TaskAttribute("solution-dir", Required = true)]
    public DirectoryInfo SolutionDir { get; set; }

    [TaskAttribute("repository", Required = false)]
    public DirectoryInfo RepositoryPath { get; set; }
    //...
```

Usage would be:

```
<nuget-update solution-dir="file:///your/solution/dir" repository="file:///your-repository" />
```

And you probably already noticed, `solution-dir` is required, but `repository` is not.

Same for `nuget-get-files`.